# broom::tidy() calculate confidence intervals at 0.84 and 0.95 levels

Tags: r, lm, broom

Is there a nifty work around to calculate the confidence intervals at two levels using broom::tidy()?

Specifically, I want to calculate the confidence intervals at two levels rather than one. I am not entirely sure what the best approach might be. So I'd like something like this:

```
model %>%
   tidy(conf.int = TRUE, level = c(0.84, 0.95)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `model %>% summary(conf.int = TRUE, ...) %>% tidy()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use multiple different confidence intervals for the same model, you could try the following. Using `map_dfr` from `purrr`, you can indicate multiple different confidence levels and then use in the `tidy` function. Here is an example using mtcars data. An additional column has been added to indicate the level for that particular model result.

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
  
map_dfr(
  c(.84, .95),
  ~cbind(tidy(x = mod, conf.int = T, conf.level = .x), level = .x)
)
```

**Output**

```
         term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value  conf.low conf.high level
1 (Intercept) 37.285126  1.877627 19.857575 8.241799e-19 34.579856 39.990396  0.84
2          wt -5.344472  0.559101 -9.559044 1.293959e-10 -6.150020 -4.538923  0.84
3 (Intercept) 37.285126  1.877627 19.857575 8.241799e-19 33.450500 41.119753  0.95
4          wt -5.344472  0.559101 -9.559044 1.293959e-10 -6.486308 -4.202635  0.95
```